# CSS Font rendering issue on Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, fonts, rendering

I have generated this custom font using icomoon.
The problem is: when I use it on Firefox (27.0.1), it cuts it by half, as you can see in here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyYMq.png
(you can see the one above works perfectly, but the main one nope).

Now comes the weirdest part: I started doing other stuff, and there was this call to "fadeOut" function from jQuery to it's sibling element. Then, WHILE it's fading, it fixes the font! When the fade is over, It "unfixes" it. I tried checking jQuery's implementation of fadeOut, but couldn't figure out.

Here is a jsfiddle to simulate it:
http://jsfiddle.net/nU7Pj/

```
<div id="wrap">
    <span class="icon-wee"></span>
</div>
<a href="#" id="click">Click to fade</a>

$(document).ready(function() {       
    $('#click').on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        $('#wrap').fadeOut(2000, function() {
            $(this).show();   
        });
    });
});
```

Just open it on firefox and click on the anchor.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix?

Comment: Is the fiddle supposed to display the problem shown in the picture? I don't see it, I see the whole word "wee."

Comment: Yes, it was supposed to display the problem. Now that you mentioned, I tried it on different computers and it was normal. Perhaps it's some issue with an installed extension on the computer I was coding. I'll check it out